# How to correctly use SetServiceStatus to tell Windows my service is stopping?

Tags: c, windows-services

Sorry about the length of the sample, but in order to get all the required components of a service it has to be this long.

Using the help of others here I've managed to get a service that starts cleanly, but now it won't stop cleanly.

On the first attempt to stop it quickly gives the error

```
Could not stop the My service service on local computer
The service did not return an error. This could be an internal Windows error or an internal service error
If the problem persists, contact your system administrator
```

and the service continues to run, even after the 5 minutes that the sleep loop takes.

On the second attempt to stop, task manager shows the process stops immediately, but the Service Manager takes a very long time to give the error

```
Could not stop the My service service on local computer
Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
```

And here is the source code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsvc.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MY_SVC_NAME "My service"
#define THE_PROG "\"C:\\Program Files\\My software\\bin\\The Prog.exe\""
#define SLEEP_TIME 300000

SERVICE_STATUS ServiceStatus;
SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE hStatus;

void WINAPI ServiceMain(DWORD argc, LPSTR argv);
void WINAPI ControlHandler(DWORD request);
void InitService();


int cont_running = 1;

DWORD WINAPI ServiceHandlerProc(DWORD ControlCode, DWORD a, void *b, void *c)
{
  switch (ControlCode) {
  case SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP :
    cont_running = 0;
    ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint=0;
    ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
    ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState  = SERVICE_STOP_PENDING;
    ServiceStatus.dwWaitHint =2000;
    SetServiceStatus (hStatus, &ServiceStatus);
    Sleep(1000);
    ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState  = SERVICE_STOPPED;
    SetServiceStatus (hStatus, &ServiceStatus);
    break;
  case SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN :
    cont_running = 0;
    ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint=0;
    ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
    ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState  = SERVICE_STOP_PENDING;
    ServiceStatus.dwWaitHint =2000;
    SetServiceStatus (hStatus, &ServiceStatus);
    Sleep(1000);
    ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState  = SERVICE_STOPPED;
    SetServiceStatus (hStatus, &ServiceStatus);
    break;
  }

  return 0;

}

void WINAPI ServiceMain(DWORD argc, LPSTR argv)
{
  int hServiceStatus;

  ServiceStatus.dwServiceType        = SERVICE_WIN32;
  ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState       = SERVICE_START_PENDING;
  ServiceStatus.dwControlsAccepted   = SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP | SERVICE_ACCEPT_SHUTDOWN;
  ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode      = 0;
  ServiceStatus.dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 0;
  ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint         = 0;
  ServiceStatus.dwWaitHint           = 0;

  hServiceStatus = RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx(MY_SVC_NAME, ServiceHandlerProc,0);
  /*
  if (hStatus == (SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE)0) {
    return;
  }
  */

  Sleep(1000);

  ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint=0;
  ServiceStatus.dwWaitHint=0;
  ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState=SERVICE_RUNNING;
  SetServiceStatus( hServiceStatus, &ServiceStatus);

  InitService();

  return;
}

void InitService()
{
  cont_running=1;
  do {
    system(THE_PROG);
    Sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
  } while (cont_running);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{
  SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY ServiceStartTable[2];
  ServiceStartTable[0].lpServiceName = MY_SVC_NAME;
  ServiceStartTable[0].lpServiceProc = (LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION)ServiceMain;
  ServiceStartTable[1].lpServiceName = NULL;
  ServiceStartTable[1].lpServiceProc = NULL;


  if (!StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(ServiceStartTable))
  {
    DWORD err = GetLastError();
    if (err == ERROR_FAILED_SERVICE_CONTROLLER_CONNECT)
      return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I've referred to the following documents without success
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809975.aspx
LUA Service Reference Manual

Comment: Check the return value from `SetServiceStatus()` and check `GetLastError()` if it failed. I also think you need to declare `cont_running` as `volatile` otherwise any change made to `cont_running` will not be visible to `InitService()`.

Comment: I guess I'm going to have to go through the hassle of creating a log file, just to do debug printf's as there's no stdout on a service. Unless there is another way?

Comment: You could write to the event viewer but no less hassle than the log file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be with your `SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE hStatus` global variable: it is not assigned anywhere in the program, but it is used quite a few times.

Also, the local variable `int hServiceStatus` makes no sense at all.

Solution: remove the `hServiceStatus` local variable and replace each use of `hServiceStatus` with the correct `hStatus` variable.

HINT: Maybe you are already aware of this, but you should set the STOP_PENDING status just when you receive the control command, and set the STOPPED only when you have really stopped the working thread.

Comment: That's the problem with copying and pasting other people's code without a full understanding of how it all works. I finally get the picture now. Thanks.

Comment: And with ignoring compiler warnings: `'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE'` :-P